# How can I get all windows services in LabVIEW?

Tags: windows, service, labview

Is there any command to list all **windows services** (stopped and started)? I am trying to do it in *LabVIEW* using **System Exec.vi**. Any other suggestions to do it within LabVIEW are accepted as well.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically, or are you just interested in viewing it?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started. Feed this string into System Exec.vi (without quotes): "sc queryex type= service state= all". I used [this](https://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/656/list-all-windows-services-on-the-command-line) article at commandlinefu.com as a guide.

Edit: I poked around a little bit and it looks like "**sc query**" is enough of a command to get all services.

[image: sc queryex type= service state= all]

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to see the list, and don't need programmatic access, I would recommend the [LabVIEW Task Manager from LAVA](https://lavag.org/files/file/245-labview-task-manager-lvtm/).

Comment: Thank you for answer dear Adrian. I have already done it by using [Service Application Manager for LabVIEW](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/ru/nid/215588)